# Increment with text value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am making a log file in Excel for some laboratory samples. In this log I record the date, the sample ID, the box where the sample is stored, and the box-position. For example:

```
SampleID    Study        Date      Box   Position    
12345       SomeStudy    date      1     A3
12346       SomeStudy    date      1     A4
```

The positions always start from position A3 and go up to A12, then they go from B1 to B12 etc... all the way up to H11.

So what I would like to do in Excel is to use an IF statement which checks the cell above it for values and splits text from numbers.

If the last value for instance was A7 then the next one would be A8 and so one, until it reaches A12; if the value is A12 the next value should be B1, and so on ...

Comment: Do you want to do this with formula or VBA?

Comment: If you want formulas, you'll need helper columns, as you can't run a formula over itself.  Also, when the text gets split, where do the resulting strings go? They couldn't go in column B, C, etc. since there's data.  Could this be done on a separate sheet instead?

Comment: I think the easiest way to go is formula as I have very little knowledge of VBA...

Answer (score 0):

Returns value of cell directly above current cell

```
INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()))
```

Splitting letters and numbers [source](http://forums.excelcentral.com/index.php?/topic/491-separating-text-and-numbers-in-excel/) (replace A2 with the above)

Letters

```
LEFT(INDIRECT(...),MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},INDIRECT(...)&"0123456789"))-1)
```

Numbers

```
RIGHT(INDIRECT(...),LEN(INDIRECT(...))-MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},INDIRECT(...)&"0123456789"))+1)
```

If statement for incrementing letters

```
IF(RIGHT(...)>=12,CHAR(CODE(LEFT(...)+1),LEFT(...))
```

If statement for incrementing numbers

```
IF(RIGHT(...)>=12,1,RIGHT(...)+1)
```

Finally Wrap both of the above IF statements in a CONCATENATE()

```
=CONCATENATE(IF(...),IF(...))
```

The final formula will look like a monster when you put it all together.
you will have to seed the first cell with A1, but you should be able to drag the formula down from then on.

It would be easier if you separated the letters and numbers into different columns like position_x and position_y assuming this is some sort of grid of samples.

Comment: I believe you may have misinterpreted what the OP was asking for [or I did]. I had thought he was only looking to increment the code "A3" up to "H12" - whether those codes relate to Excel references or any random ID system doesn't appear to be relevant.

Comment: @pnuts the process repeats after H11, I have a checkup in one of my cells if the value h11 is reached the box# cell will be incremented so box 2 will start again from pos a3 to h11 and so on

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the MID function (which picks up specific characters from a text string), as well as the CHAR / CODE functions (which look at the ASCII code of characters, and vice versa). Because your data only involves 1 letter, this is relatively striaght-forward, as follows (for Cell D3, which looks like the position above for the 2nd line of data, which currently shows "A4" as a value):

```
=IF(VALUE(MID(D2,2,2))<11,LEFT(D2)&VALUE(MID(D2,2,2))+1,IF(LEFT(D2)="H","A3",CHAR(CODE(LEFT(D2))+1)&3))
```

What this does is: check the last 1 (or 2) characters of the position above - this is the number. If that number is < 12, it brings in the 1st character of the position above, and then increments the number by 1. Otherwise, it increments the ASCII character of the 1st character of the text above by 1, and tacks on a 3.

I have tested this and confirmed that it works as intended - but only for the range that you specified.

**Edited to reflect the fact that the cycle stops at 11, and recycles to A3 after H11.**

Answer (score 0):

Alternative interpretation, assuming the start of the series is entered in E1 and the formula is copied down from E2 to suit:

```
 =IF(E1="H11","A3",IF(LEN(E1)=3,IF(RIGHT(E1,2)="12",CHAR(CODE(LEFT(E1))+1)&1,LEFT(E1)&RIGHT(E1,2)+1),LEFT(E1)&RIGHT(E1)+1))
```

Comment: @esecules As you can see, the formulas which pnuts & I created are basically the same thing - just combinations of the MID/LEN/RIGHT/LEFT functions which are common ways to split strings in Excel, and the CHAR/CODE functions, which are common tools to translate characters into numbers. You should become familiar with these tools to create similar formulas in the future; it may help if you break each formula into smaller chunks (make 1 cell equal to "IF(E1="H11",TRUE,FALSE)", and then make another cell refer to that cell to show the formula in each seperate part.